# Laravel 5 - Duplicate Data in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I need solution ! my problem is when i get data from table i have **duplicated** field my case i have **table User** and i whant get **Date** from Table **User** when i get and **display** in **view** like :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   echo $user->date .' - ';
@endforeach
```

the problem if Date duplicated it show me : **2011 -2011 -2014 - 2011**

some help

Answer (score 0):

We should see your query before answering but you should give a try to this;

You may need to use `distinct()` in your query as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line with collection methods.

```
{{ $users->pluck('date')->unique()->implode(' - ') }}
```